# Making a custom blot in typescript

Tags: typescript, quill, parchment

I'd like to be able to extend native blots as seen in [cloning medium w/ parchment](https://quilljs.com/guides/cloning-medium-with-parchment/). I am using angular2 with typescript, and typescript does not believe that `BlockEmbed` is a real constructor.

Using the following code (pretty much directly from above tutorial):
    let BlockEmbed = Quill.import('blots/block/embed');

```
class DividerBlot extends BlockEmbed { }
DividerBlot.blotName = 'divider';
DividerBlot.tagName = 'hr';
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this has worked for me:

```
const BlockEmbed = Quill.import('blots/block/embed') as { new (node, value): Object };
export class DividerBlot extends BlockEmbed {
    static blotName = 'divider';
    static tagName = 'hr';
}
```